# Spring REST Service on Tomcat with Gradle

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat

I've created a REST service with Spring and am having trouble understanding how I get this deployed to a Tomcat server.

I'm familiar with putting applications on a Tomcat instance with servlet mappings and such but it appears that this is all handled in the Spring annotations within the Java classes.  I've got the `'war'` plugin enabled in Gradle and everything seems to export fine.  I'm just confused because Spring requires an Application class to run the controllers so how do I get this to work with something like the web.xml file?

I may not even be on the right track.  I also read something about deploying the .jar as the REST endpoint but I don't know where to begin there.

If someone could just give me a high-level overview of what needs to be done to get a Spring REST service such as the one built [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) to run on a Tomcat instance, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Java 8
Spring
Gradle 2.2.1
Windows 7

Comment: From what I understand you are talking about Spring Boot, right? Otherwise, you do not need an Application class, you need a ServletFilter / ContextListener to load the configuration.

Comment: My understanding of Spring Boot (which may be incorrect) is that it includes an embedded server for a standalone application.  What I'd like to be able to have is one Tomcat instance with multiple applications/contexts deployed to it.  Those applications would simply be REST services to back Javascript applications.

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using? Did you read http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html or http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#overview-web ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an app (war package) with Spring servlet and spring context (there are looooots of tutorials in the internet). You need to include component scanning (refer to the article here http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-scanning-components/ for an example).

Spring scans components (and your controller) and recognizes @Controller or @RestController annotation and automatically assigns it to the routing. And that's it :).

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like you are using Spring Boot, you should only need to mark the Tomcat dependency as `providedRuntime`, as described at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-gradle-packaging :

```
...
apply plugin: 'war'

war {
    baseName = 'myapp'
    version =  '0.5.0'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    ...
}
```

Then your war should be deployable to an external Tomcat instance.